# Should I have a say when a Documentation topic that I have contributed to is deleted?

Tags: feature-request, documentation

Imagine spending a couple of hours writing about something you want to share with other people. Then someone comes along and deletes all of your work.

I made a document about hacking. It was approved and I added examples. Then someone requested that my whole document be deleted because one of my examples supposedly had nothing to do with the topic. His change was accepted and I awoke to find my whole document deleted.

I believe that I should have had a chance to defend the document before it was deleted or there should be some kind of rep limitation to prevent lower reputation users from deleting the contributions of higher reputation users.

Comment: I don't think that "hacking" is a topic that has any place on Documentation.\

Comment: It was approved. And it is a type of coding? Why wouldn't it be accepted. Have you seen some of the documents?

Comment: The topic being approved just goes to show that the system isn't perfect. If you expected a perfect system then by golly you came to the wrong place.

Comment: I'd like to take a look at the documentation you wrote first, so we can draw a more objective conclusion here.  I largely agree with everyone else thus far, though.

Comment: I agree with @Makoto, what I've said is based on what I imagine a Documentation topic on "hacking" would look like, and I would have to see the topic itself to give a real opinion one way or the other. If you can get us a link, 10k+ rep users can still see it.

Comment: "[Hacking](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/H/hacker.html)" is pretty general. Do you mean "[cracking](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/C/cracker.html)"? Even that's vague, but at least it points in a particular direction.

Comment: [Was this the one?](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/9167/hacking#t=20170221194301187)  If so it's time to distill my thoughts into an answer...

Comment: "Hacking is a way of gaining access to an electrical entity without permission. Hacking is not all bad, it could help you find your gmail password for example. Not to mention improving your coding skills. Hacking is a different type of coding, and Python is the best language for it." Yeesh.

Comment: Hacking or cracking?

Answer (score 8):

Okay.  I *think* [that you're talking about this Documentation entry](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/9167/hacking#t=20170221194301187), and from what I can tell, its removal was appropriate.

Here's the synopsis:

- Your topic discussed "hacking" in a very script-kiddie sense, without *ever* actually taking the time to elaborate on what hacking *was* and why one would do it in Python.
- You've only created *two* entries, and these entries aren't horrendously complex.  It isn't like you've lost apparent hours to this.
- You discuss a bruteforce attack against a service which ***very likely*** has very good guards against bruteforce attacks.  Seriously.  This is genuinely amateur-level discussions about that type of attack.
- You don't really discuss anything specific about hacking; you're simply saying, "Oh, these are some really awesome scripts I use to "hack"; you can too!"...which is the very definition of "script kiddie".

I own a book called [Gray Hat Python](https://www.nostarch.com/ghpython.htm) which does a good job of elaborating what one can do with Python for good and less-than-good purposes to do with network security.  I'd trust it as a better resource on "hacking" as it were than the document written.

I don't necessarily have an issue with the topic of security in applications existing; I don't have an issue with the topic of known bruteforce attacks existing.  But I *do* have an issue with this piece of documentation as written; it's never going to educate anyone, and it's only useful for script kiddies overall.

Comment: I was just showing doing, like simple examples to start with. Also, where would I talk about hacking in general? In the introduction? Examples? There are no where else.

Comment: @Elodin:  Security is a topic that I'm not 100% sure fits yet; I mean, I don't have a problem with it here, but I'm not sure it fits.